# SQL table event store as a queue in Qt App

Tags: c++, qt, distributed, cqrs, event-sourcing

I need some advice on my Qt app using just Qt classes. I can accept QtNetwork and QSql modules as solutions but not "3rd party" tools such as RabbitMQ etc.

I'm using "Event Store As A Queue" (see [Greg Young](http://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf) page 46) with CQRS with Event Sourcing. I have a simple SQL table storing events with a unique sequential ID. Thus, can track the "event store pointer" to be used for by a "chasing process".

Goal: I would like to run multiple processes to handle the events as "pop them from the queue" ensuring they are treated only once....

At this stage I only have interprocess communication via the DB (mySQL,SQLite) and setup a shared table doing a TTL (Time To Live) as a heard beat list. The "TOP" process is acting as the worker. So if it dies the TTL times out and the next one takes over. The TOP worker thus then cleans out "stale processes". This has some delay equal at least to the TTL eg. 5s which is not an optimal situation.

I now would like to let other processes also take on some work. I could change the "TOP" role from Worker to  Dispatcher but then I would need communication to the other processes to give work (eg. Process Events 100-200). Going via the DB to dispatch does not look like a good idea in terms of performance so I can signal event Ids via QTcp** classes...not a real problem. But, then it brings some other questions to mind: What happens when my dispatcher dies? Is it a good practice that one process play Worker and Dispatcher? Fail-over? Redundancy? Scalability?

I'm sure there must be some simple solution without breaking my head. Load balancer? Same questions apply. Load-balancer is just a dispatcher. Seems that I need to keep a heartbeat between processes via TCP. Would be faster....Implementing something like the RAFT protocol is an overkill at this stage! Not sure if other distributed design patterns or protocols apply. I do have a REST framework... maybe ATOM? PubSubHubHub and WebHooks? Do no like WebSockets since we need to persist TCP connections...

Thought, ideas, suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to implement a queueing mechanism on top of the db is it worth it? I see that your system can not afford loosing messages, but once you have the TTL looks like you don't really need it.

"Goal: I would like to run multiple processes to handle the events as "pop them from the queue" ensuring they are treated only once." - http://www.eaipatterns.com/CompetingConsumers.html This is the simple solution, each worked you have running should consume it this way:
 - getting message from the "queue", mark it as retrieved for consumption and can be in such a state only a defined period of time.
 - consume.
 - change the status of the message in the queue and (re)move it.

Have your workers running in different VMs and collect statistics from each of them implementing this http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/service-watchdog/